# I would like to download all envelops form all user

Tags: api, docusignapi, envelope

I would like to download all envelopes form all users. Which api can do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To complete this task successfully you have two complete to sub-tasks:

1. Find all envelopes in the DocuSign account.
2. Loop over each envelope and download it.

I would recommend you start with #2 and ensure you know how to download a single envelope first. Lots of resources to help you out including [how to article](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/download-envelope-documents/) and [blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-downloading-documents) on this topic.

#1 is a bit more nuanced as I assume you would only want to look for the envelopes that are in **Completed** state (meaning they have been finalized and everyone signed them). I suggest you look into [how to find envelopes based on status change](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/list-envelope-status-changes/) and understand how this works to confirm you can do that.